# Setting Zend APPLICATION_ENV for Command Line Scripts

Tags: php, zend-framework

The standard practice for setting the environment (production/staging/development) with the Zend Framework is using `SetEnv` in the Apache config (or `.htaccess`) to set the `APPLICATION_ENV`. This obviously works well for web requests, but what about running command line scripts (that are still part of the application, using the same bootstrapping, and rely on the correct `APPLICATION_ENV`)?

Any best practices for that? Right now I'm just dropping a `.environment.php` file in my `cli` directory - it's included if it exists (similar to `.htaccess` I guess), and can be used to set the environment.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/APPLICATION-ENV-for-cli-scripts-staging-td3582445.html) will help.

Answer (score 17):

### From a terminal

For (linux)command-line only usage you could add following line to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export APPLICATION_ENV=development
```

Or add the line to `/etc/profile` to set the environment variable for all users.

For more information:

- [Howto: Set environment variables in Windows 7](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/11/29/set-environment-variables-in-windows-7-for-java/)
- [Howto: Set environment variables in Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/)

### From a crontab

Cron uses a clean/empty environment and doesn't look at `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` for the APPLICATION_ENV or other environment variables.

Just define the environment variable inside the crontab:

```
APPLICATION_ENV=development
0 0 * * *   /usr/bin/php /path/to/your_script.php
```

For more information:

- [Cron and Crontab usage and examples](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)

Comment: Yeah, but if the script is called automatically (say, through cron) that work apply - correct?

Comment: Late follow up I know - those all work, I was looking for a singular way to set the `APPLICATION_ENV`, instead of setting it in numerous places (`.bashrc`, in the crontab, etc). Guess that's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the script

```
APPLICATION_ENV="local" php cli.php
```

Comment: if it's a variable without spaces or any special charcater, you can dismiss `"` like this `APPLICATION_ENV=local php cli.php`